# store user name and password in a file instead of using database in C

Tags: c

I am purely a beginner to programming. I want to store user name and password in a file ( Let's say XML or any other ). I will need to use that file for storing user name and password for authentication of my website instead of using database. Can anyone advise me what type of file should i use and provide link if any such codes? Please take in mind that I have to do it in C language. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a home work question so let me give you some ideas.  Also storing a user name and a password in a file in clear text is a bad idea.

you can use the folowing std lib function to do what you need

- [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/) to open the file
- [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/) to write to the file
- [fclose](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose/) to close the file

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i need more specific. But I need to check whether the user name and password match to my stored data or not. Do you have any sample coding to do such ?

Comment: Then add fgets to the list. as for specific Google fopen tutorial and you will find all the info you need.  like http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html